# Generate series from postgres to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Can anyone fluent in both MySQL and PostgreSQL translate this to MySQL?

```
SELECT *
FROM  generate_series(DATE_TRUNC('day', NOW() - interval '30 day'),
                            DATE_TRUNC('day', NOW()),
                            interval '1 day'
                           )
```

I know that generate_series() does not exist in MySQL. Is there a similar function?

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent.  MySQL doesn't have CTEs, `generate_series()`, or even window functions.

If you have a table that is big enough (in this case 31 rows), you can do:

```
select (curdate() - interval (@rn := @rn + 1) day) as dte
from t cross join
     (select @rn := -1)
limit 31;
```